# Multi-line Highlight in Vim

Tags: vim, highlight, lines

I am currently writing a plugin in Vim that needs to highlight arbitrary lines in a file
at the same time.

My approach so far has been implementing `match` with the line number to highlight it, but the problem is that I would need to add `|` for every other line in a file and append that information and then call it every time the window gets redrawn.

There is another problem with `match` in my case, and that is that a line that may not have any whitespace would not look highlighted (`match` only highlights existing text/whitespace).

So even if I had `match` rewrite the window and highlighting all the lines I need, from a user's perspective this wouldn't be to useful if the highlighting doesn't show anything if  there is no whitespace/text.

Can I get any suggestions in how to effectively show/display/highlight (I'm open to different implementations to solve my problem) arbitrary lines in a file at the same time regardless of amount of text or whitespace?

Edit: My main request is to be able to highlight lines *by line number* not by regex
matching. So any solution should need to be flexible enough to accept a Line number to match.

Edit: `signs` is the answer to my problem, and I found this tutorial the best way to grasp and implement what I needed: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/runpaint/vim-recipes/blob/master/text/07_navigation/12_bookmarking_lines_with_visible_markers.html

Comment: Have you looked into vim's `signs`?  They are a bit of a pain to work with but there are plugins out there that use them for a similar purpose, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: that *might* be it (reading the docs section about it)

Answer (score 2):

I would use `region` rather than `match`.  Here is part of my manuscript syntax file that highlights speech:

```
:syntax region msSpeech start=/"/ end=/"\|\n\n/
:highlight msSpeech guifg=#000088
```

It starts with a double quote and ends with another double quote or the end of the paragraph.  It will highlight multiple lines if need be.

Comment: My need is to highlight entire lines baseed on the line number not on regex matches... Reading the documentation for region it does not accept a line number for this.

Comment: You can use `/\%10l/` to "search" for line 10, and so highlight it.  Unfortunately, I don't see how to make it highlight multiple lines (apart from looping and testing for modulo 2 etc).

Comment: @13ren That only matches existing characters, not the whole visual line, as OP needed.